# Network performance deteriorates when uninvolved device on switch is shut down

Tags: networking, performance

I am witnessing very counter-intuitive effect in my network setup.

I have a network setup with three devices (let's call them *server*, *laptop* and *nettop*, all running Linux, details below) connected to a gigabit ethernet switch.

I measure network throughput (a) by transferring a file from the *server* to the *laptop* using `scp` and (b) using `iperf -s` on the *server* and `iperf -c` on the *laptop*.

When I perform the throughput test while all three devices are up and running, I get an ok-ish performance of roughly 40 MB/s (SSH) or 280 Mbits/s (iperf).

However, as soon as I **turn off** the *nettop* which isn't involved in the measurement process at all, I get a lousy performance of roughly 3.5 MB/s (SSH) or 58 Mbits/s (iperf).

If it was the other way round, I would try to find out if the *nettop* is interfering with the transfer somehow. But the fact that performance **drops** by an order of magnitude when I turn it off leaves me mystified.

This behavior is perfectly reproducible. As soon as the *nettop* gets pingable, the performance rises immediately. As soon as it is off, the performance drops.

I tried cutting power to the switch for a minute and shuffling around the ethernet ports on the switch with no effect.

So my question is: What could possibly cause the effect I am witnessing? Where could I look in order to narrow down the cause of the problem?

### Details on the Setup

#### Nettop

- Foxconn nT-330i, Intel Atom 330
- Built in Atheros AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
- Ubuntu 10.04 (lucid), Kernel 2.6.32-29, amd64

#### Laptop

- Thinkpad R61, Intel Core 2 Duo T8300
- Built in Broadcom BCM5787M Gigabit Ethernet Controller
- Ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric), Kernel 3.0.0-16, amd64

#### Server

- AMD Athlon 64 X2
- Intel 82574L Gigabit Ethernet Controller (e1000e)
- Debian 6.0.4 (squeeze), Kernel 2.6.32-5, amd64

#### Switch

- Level One GSW-0806 8-Port Gigabit Switch

The server has two additional network interfaces, one hooked up to a cable modem, the other one to a wifi router.

The server runs a DHCP server which the nettop and laptop acquire their addresses from. It also runs numerous other services, including KVM running two VMs.

#### IP-Addressing

All devices are in the `10.2.3.0/24` network. Server has `10.2.3.1`, laptop `10.2.3.37`, nettop `10.2.3.42`. The Server interface connected to the Wifi has `10.2.4.1/24`. Neither the nettop's nor the laptop's wifi adaptor is enabled.

#### ethtool output

`ethtool` shows the following adaptor settings. These outputs are unaffected by turning off and on the *nettop*.

On the server:

```
# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: on
    Supports Wake-on: pumbag
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000001 (1)
    Link detected: yes
```

On the laptop:

```
# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Supports Wake-on: g
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x000000ff (255)
                   drv probe link timer ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err
    Link detected: yes
```

Comment: What does your IP addressing look like? I think its no coincidence that you seem to drop to 802.11G speeds.

Comment: Added the IP-Addressing to the question. Do you need any more details?

Comment: Could you take the dhcp server out of the equation and assign static IP addresses to nettop and laptop?

Comment: All I can think of is a bad switch.  You seem to be using an off-brand model, and they often do weird things.  I would try a known good switch, or experiment with different cables in different ports.  You might also do a wireshark or tcpdump on the nettop looking for anything interesting.

Comment: The only thing tcpdump on the nettop reveals are some MDNS queries and responses. I'll probably have to get hold of another switch and see if the effect persists. :-/

Comment: @aseq: I assigned the IPs statically and it didn't have any effect.

Comment: Can you 100% confirm that there's only minimal traffic to/from the `nettop` during your test?

Comment: do any services either on the server or laptop (or VM's in KVM) connect to nettop?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I definitely can. I ran a tcpdump on the `nettop` again just now, performing another test and all it showed was a single ARP `who has` query and a subsequent response.

Comment: @Rex: No. The nettop is a vanilla Ubuntu install that nothing in my network connects to or is being connected from. It just sits there and does nothing at all.

Comment: In case things are set to auto negotiate. What if you manually set the speed of all the ethernet ports to 1 gbit?

Comment: @aseq: I just checked. The settings of both ethernet controllers remain at 1000 Mb/s Full Duplex before, during and after the transfer irregardles of the nettop running or not.

Comment: Remove the switch and connect the laptop directly to the server.

Comment: Well... I'd go with mfarver's suggestion and try a different switch.

Comment: @Craig: Should have thought of trying this myself. :-) I did it and now I have full speed without the nettop. So it definitely must the switch. Thanks!

Comment: This type of question should be tagged "x-files". I'm trying to think what the switch does when you unplugged the nettop box. It should invalidate the MAC address connected to that port and that's it. The port goes down. What if it goes into crazy/hub mode? Can you plug more computers into it, unplug nettop and see if the other computers see the server-laptop traffic?

Comment: @gtirloni: I settled with the explanation that the switch is broken and ordered a new one, from Cisco this time. If you want to put more research into it, I could send you the broken one, though. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly as mfarver suggested: My switch is broken. I replaced it with a new one (a Cisco SG-200-08 this time) and now everything works like a charm, regardless of which additional devices are connected and which aren't.

Answer (score 1):

> However, as soon as I turn off the nettop which isn't involved in the
>   measurement process at all, I get a lousy performance of roughly 3.5
>   MB/s (SSH) or 58 Mbits/s (iperf).

This strongly indicates that the switch (which is a no-brand so-so specimen) drops the entire backplane to 100mbit when you ***disconnect*** the nettop.

I agree it is worse than weird - it's unacceptable.

But there you have it.